# Null value returned by mysql_fetch_assoc()

Tags: mysql, null

I am calling `mysql_fetch_assoc($res)` on a result of a query. The query is good, there are other results returned in the same row. The last column is always null. Why is this?

Code (has been abbreviated, so no comments on the style please):

```
$qy = "SELECT * FROM `entries` WHERE `dag`=".$_POST['day'];
        $res = mysql_query($qy, $sql);


        $d = '';
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
        $d .= $row['text'];
        $e = json_encode($row);

        echo json_encode(array("status" => "success", "data" => $d, "error" => $e));
```

`$d` will equal `null` and `$e` will equal `{"status":"success","data":null,"error":"{\"dag\":\"DATA\",\"afstand\":\"DATA\",\"tijd\":\"DATA\",\"max\":\"DATA\",\"tottijd\":\"DATA\",\"odo\":\"DATA\",\"van\":\"DATA\",\"naar\":\"DATA\",\"weer\":\"DATA\",\"text\":null}"}` where `DATA` is the correct data. The `text` column is `null`.

The `text` column has the `VARCHAR` type, with a maximum of 5000 characters. The text in the field I am trying to retrieve is 1800 characters long.

Comment: `print_r` gives me the correct data, including the missing data, so the column exists. I renamed the column, but the problem still exists

Comment: Please note that the `mysql_xx()` functions are considered obsolete and should be avoided. You are **strongly** recommended to switch to either the [very similar] `mysqli_xx()` functions, or the PDO library.

Comment: by the way, are you properly escaping `$_POST['day']` ? If not, then you have a wide open security hole in your SQL query.

Comment: Yes, the normal code is different, and I have it properly escaped ;) A question, what is different about the `mysqli_xx` functions?

Comment: Read the Mysql-PHP documentation, mysql is deprecated since years ago

Comment: In short, the `mysqli_xx()` functions are newer. The old library is no longer being maintained, so that alone is a big reason to switch, but `mysqli` also has some additional features. It can be called in an OOP style. Plus it allows parameterised queries (which avoids the need for escaping your fields at all). There's more, no room here; but read the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer to my own question of two years ago.

The problem was encoding: The `text` column contains text, which was not UTF-8 encoded. When I wrapped the code to fetch the `text` in a `utf8_encode()`, everything worked as expected.